# return objects that are not in the mapping file from nhibernate hql

Tags: nhibernate, orm, hql

the title says pretty much what I'm trying to do. I have nhibernate hql with select case

```
select application.SubmissionDate, count(candidates)
from Application as application group by application.SubmissionDate
```

I would like to have the return values from this query into an object (which is not in nhibernate mapping file) called 'CountPerDay' object

```
class CountPerDay {
public DateTime Date,
public int Count
}
```

does nHibernate has sort of build in feature /methods to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [**Ad-hoc mapping**](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/06/29/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+LosTechies+%28LosTechies%29) for NHibernate:

```
string hql = @"select application.SubmissionDate as Date, count(candidates) as Count 
               from Application as application 
               group by application.SubmissionDate";

var count = session.CreateQuery(hql)
                   .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(CountPerDay)))
                   .List<CountPerDay>();
```

Comment: thanks! updated the code and change CountPerDay.Count to long and it works.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that [transformation only works if you query using a native SQL query](https://nhibernate.info/previous-doc/v5.2/ref/querysql.html#querysql-non-managed-entities) (not _HQL_). In @rebelliard's answer he's calling `session.CreateQuery(hql)`. This will still complain that the table isn't mapped. Calling `session.CreateSqlQuery(...)` instead should work though.